# How to identify how to shift from sin to cos in sinoid signals

Tags: trigonometry, signal-processing

I have been working with sinus signals recently.
The problem is as following:

Simplify $x(t)$ to a simple sinoid function:
$$ x(t) = 10 \cos (\omega t + 0.42) + 4.2 \cos(\omega t - 1.3) - 6 \sin(\omega t + 0.38) $$

My initial instict was to convert the $6\sin(\omega t + 0.38)$ to a cosine, then convert all the factors to complex numbers to get the complete wave.

I have always thought of $\sin (x)$ as $\cos (x) $ shifted by $\pi/2$, so I did:
$$ 6 \sin (\omega t + 0.38) = 6 \cos (\omega t + 0.38 + \pi/2)$$

Now having three signals to add, I converted them to their complex representations:
$$ f(x) = 10e^{j(\omega t + 0.42)} + 4.2e^{j(\omega t -1.3)} - 6e^{j(\omega t + 0.38 +\pi/2)}$$
I could now split it into two factors to find the phase shift:
$$ f(x) = e^{j(\omega t)} * (10e^{0.42j} + 4.2e^{-1.3j} -6e^{(0.38+\pi/2)j} ) $$
I converted that to vectors in cartesian space, and got:
$$ p(x) = \begin{bmatrix} 9.13\\4.08 \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} 1.12\\-4.05 \end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix} 12.48\\-5.54 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 12.48\\-5.54 \end{bmatrix}$$
Converting that back to eulers form, I got
$$ A = \sqrt{12.48^2 + -5.54} = 13.65 $$
$$ \theta = \arctan(-5.54/12.48) = -0.42$$

Which combined with the first factor. gave me the real part of the function:
$$ x(t) = 13.65\cos(\omega t - 0.42)$$, which unfortunately didn't match up with the graph.
However, I noticed the first two factors added correctly up. So it turned out, if I instead expressed
$$ 6 \sin (\omega t + 0.38) = 6 \cos (\omega t + 0.38 - \pi/2)$$
(this time doing $-\pi/2$ and not $+\pi/2$), I got the correct answer
$$ f(x) = 9.79 \cos ( \omega t +0.61 )$$

So, basically my question is, how do I always make sure I convert from sin to cos correctly? Should I always take minus $\pi/2$, or are there cases where I should add it instead.
Earlisr I found that the graphs of $g(x) = \sin(x)$ and $g(x) = \cos(x+\pi/2)$, matches up, so I don't understand why it didn't in this case.

Sorry if this seems like a very stupid question, but I've been trying to find some sense in it but I can't really figure it out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Earlisr I found that the graphs of $g(x) = sin(x)$ and $g(x) = cos(x+\pi/2)$, matches up" -- no, [$\cos(x+\pi/2) = -\sin(x)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=cos%28x%2Bpi%2F2%29), they are negative of each other.

Comment: I believe there is a mistake at $6\sin(\omega t +38)=6\cos(\omega t+38 \color{red}- \frac {\pi}{2})$

Comment: I wonder if the underlying question here is, how to simplify all these: $\sin(x+\pi/2)$ or $\cos(x+\pi/2)$ or $\sin(x-\pi/2)$ or $\cos(x-\pi/2)$ or $\sin(x+3\pi/2)$ or ...?

Comment: @peterwhy I see what I did wrong, thanks a lot for the negatives of each other tip. I apparently did the opposite thing and saw that $cos(x) = sin (x+\pi/2)$, which is the opposite to what I had in mind. But yes you are correct, that was the question.

Comment: @WindSoul yeah thats correct, I mostly wondered why that is but I see now that I had tried converting the opposite way. Wish I could help you with the generator but no idea about any of that unfortunately.